# Vertically aligning text inside a span

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/2R36y/

Relevant span code -

### CSS

```
nav ul li a span {
    font: 30px"Dosis", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

### HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
                <span>About</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
                <span>Portfolio</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
                <span>Contact</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/2R36y/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is by using `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` - you can also use `line-height` since the `<span>` has a fixed height.

```
nav ul li a:hover span {
    font: 30px"Dosis", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2R36y/1/

Comment: is it possible to have the span move to the right side of the image like in my example?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2R36y/3/? - if so, just repeat the same for each `<span>`

Comment: In that, Home still pops up on top of the blue box, I want to pop up to the right side of the blue box, for example.

Comment: It *is* appearing on the right side of the blue box, isn't it?

Comment: Screenshot of what your last JSFiddle looks like -> http://i.imgur.com/6S7yFAh.png

Comment: That's odd - I'm not seeing that on Chrome 28, Windows 7. You can also use `line-height` since the `<span>` has a fixed height - take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2R36y/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34498/discussion-between-narabhut-and-adrift)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table`.

```
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    display: table; 
}

nav ul li a:hover span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```